# Где взять токен для сообщества vk?

Tags: vkontakte-api, бот, вконтакте

> Откройте раздел «Управление сообществом» («Управление страницей», если у Вас публичная страница), выберите вкладку «Работа с API» и нажмите «Создать ключ доступа».

Взято из офф. документации ВК. ([Ссылка](https://vk.com/dev.php?method=bots_docs&f=1.1.%20%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0)). Я сделал все по инструкции и в упомянутом разделе отсутствует вкладка "Работа с API" (раньше была). Как получить токен?

Answer (score 0):

Очень странно, ведь раздел никуда не подевался. Проверьте, есть ли у вас необходимые права в сообществе (являетесь руководителем сообщества или создателем).

[image: Скриншот раздела Работа с API]

Как альтернатива, можно создать токен для приложения (["Implicit Flow для получения ключа доступа сообщества"](https://dev.vk.com/api/access-token/implicit-flow-community)) или воспользоваться [vkhost.github.io](https://vkhost.github.io).

Comment: Спасибо. Проблему решил. Оказывается мой браузер почему-то открывал мобильную версию (m.vk.com).